# How to throttle a promise that recursively retries X number of times

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, throttling

I am trying to write a promise that will be consumed by a react component. I am using `lodash` for throttling.
The idea is the component using this function should transparently invoke this function as many time as it wants without causing too many invocations.

```js
let throttledApi = throttle(() => {
    // tracking number of attempts
  let attempts = 0;
  const retryableFn = () => {
    // do I need a return before api here?
    api()
      .then((response) => {
        return response;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        attempts++;
        if (attempts === 3) throw error; // throw to the component using this functino
                // same question as above for below line
        else retryableFn();
      });
  };
}, 60 * 1000); // 1 minute


// I am using it like this
throttledFn = throttledApi();
// How do I properly use the throttled instance
// How do I try/catch properly.
// Is this thenable?
throttledFn();
```

Comment: this would be a good one to put in a codesandbox.  you could just make api() a setTimeout function to mock out.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? When asking a question, you need to explain the actual versus expected behavior. The catch probably needs to return something. that is `else return retryableFn();` ?

Comment: @terpinmd Why a codesandbox? Just use the [runnable code feature](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) that are available within SO.

Comment: thats fine, but i bet part of his issue is in his react component

Comment: @terpinmd React is not even a tag on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues, but even when those are fixed, you actually still need a promise from the throttled function, which lodash does not provide.

The issues:

- `retryableFn` is never called. The function you have passed to `throttle` only defines that function, but then does nothing with it.
- `throttledApi` **is** the throttled function, so doing `throttledFn = throttledApi()` is actually executing that throttled function and assigning its return value (which is `undefined`) to `throttledFn`. You should just work with `throttledApi` and forget about `throttledFn`
- The function that lodash's `_.throttle` creates for you doesn't return a value, so it will not be a promise (thenable) as you understandably prefer.

#### Throttling for promises

The function returned by the lodash `throttle` function does not return a value, yet in your scenario it would be good to still get a promise from it. If the request comes too fast after another one, then this promise should take some time (including the delay) to resolve.

You can write your own `throttleAsync` function. Here is one way it could be done (I've used 4 seconds as cooldown):

```js
// Generic function
const delay = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

// Generic function
const retryAsync = (asyncFunc, maxNumAttempts, timeout) => 
    asyncFunc().catch(async (error) => {
        if (--maxNumAttempts <= 0) throw error;
        await delay(timeout);
        return retryAsync(asyncFunc, maxNumAttempts, timeout);
    });

// Generic function
const throttleAsync = (asyncFunc, coolDown) => {
    let coolDownPromise = Promise.resolve();
    let responsePromise = null;
    return async function(...args) {
        console.log("Verify cooldown");
        await coolDownPromise;
        if (responsePromise) return responsePromise;
        console.log("Cooldown is over...");
        coolDownPromise = delay(coolDown);
        responsePromise = asyncFunc.call(this, ...args);
        responsePromise.finally(() => responsePromise = null).catch(() => 0);
        return responsePromise;
    };
}

// Specific function (mock)
const api = async function () {
    console.log("API called");
    await delay(100);
    if (Math.random() < .5) {
        console.log("API bumped into an error.");
        throw "API bumped into an error.";
    }
    console.log("Response received from API!");
    return { data: new Date().toLocaleTimeString() };
}

// throttle the specific function to have 4 seconds cooldown
const throttledRequest = throttleAsync(() => retryAsync(api, 3, 200), 4_000);

async function refresh() {
    try {
        const response = await throttledRequest();
        output.textContent = "The response is: " + JSON.stringify(response);
    } catch (error) {
        output.textContent = "Giving up. The error is: " + JSON.stringify(error.message ?? error);
    }
}

// I/O handling
const [button, output] = document.querySelectorAll("button, div");
button.addEventListener("click", refresh);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
<button>Make Request</button>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Think of it like that I need to call the API 3 times back to back delay or no delay doesnt matter. What I want to throttle is this whole 3 calls thing as a single unit. This chunk of code that retires 3 times will be called by a user action so it does need throttling. If you can edit your answer according to this that would be great.